# How are these MOSFETs used as a voltage divider in this circuit?

Tags: batteries, circuit-design, fuel-gauge

[image: bq34z100 circuit diagram]

I am a beginner in electronics.  I generally code and write software.  This is for one of my projects.

We are trying to use the Texas Instruments [BQ34Z100](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/bq34z100-g1)  fuel gauge IC to measure state of charge (SOC) for our battery power supply.

After reading through the datasheet I understood that an external voltage divider is needed for battery voltages greater than 4.5V, but I don't understand why they are using MOSFETs with the resistors for voltage translation from higher to lower.

Comment: Read the description of VEN in table 5-1.

Comment: The mosfets are used to switch the resistor divider when needed, otherwise the resistor divider would cause unwanted discharge of the battery.

Comment: Thank you,so when the switch connected to the VEN is closed the internal divider is disabled and the external divider circuit is used right?,sorry if am bothering with question but i am little new to this field and trying to understand and adapt these into my own projects which i am currently stuck on.

Answer (score 2):

The MOSFETs disconnect the voltage divider from the battery.

The voltage divider draws a tiny bit of current all the time.  If you want to get the longest possible run time out of your battery, every milliampere counts.

A 1 milliampere constant drain would take 24 mAh out of your battery every day.  That would discharge a 250mAh battery in less than 10 days.

The MOSFETs are arranged to connect the voltage divider only when needed.  The voltage divider then only draws current for a few minutes (or seconds) a day instead of all the time.

---

There's a note under the circuit diagram that says the MOSFETs are optional.